# Java , Android , Java EE

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee

How diferent is Java used in Android apps development from Java used to develop regular desktop applications? Can I use the skills acquired by developing Java Android applications in Java EE web development?

What is Java ME all about ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> **How diferent is Java used in Android apps development from java used to develop regular java applications?**

From a language point of view, almost identical.

From an user interface API and application life-cycle point of view, almost completely different.

> **Can i use the skills acquired by developing Java Android applications in Java EE web development?**

Yes. Your pure "Java-skills" will come in handy for sure. But as said above, the application life-cycle for instance, is completely different from most other scenarios.

> **What is Java ME all about ?**

JavaME is an older technique, typically used for phones without touch screens. It defines (compared to Android) a *very* minimal API and was originally designed to run on *very* limited devices compared to todays smart phones.

Comment: **+1** That's nice but sounds like J2ME in not so old that you can refer the word **Older** for this. The market is still flooded with devices that support J2ME.

Comment: "JavaME is an older technique, typically used for phones without touch screens" : That's not completly accurate. JavaME is used for Blackberry and Amazon Kindle development, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Android is, roughly, JavaSE without some of the more specialized features, like security layers (JSE and JAAS), GUI (AWT, Swing and Java2D).

Android's API uses the JavaME class hierarchie for OpenGL ES.

So if you know Android, you can easily move to JavaSE development.

JavaEE relies on JavaSE, but it's about server applications, so you will have to learn how it works. Look for servlets, JSP and JSF to learn more about it.

JavaME is slightly different than JavaSE. JavaME's API is smaller and less powerful than JavaSE, and slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in order to develop both for Android, Java ME and Java EE the base thing to know is Java SE. Java ME is getting old. The most popular staff to develop in Java ME is software for Blackberry.
Java EE development is pretty hard to learn technology, cause it actually consists of a big ammount of frameworks and smaller technologies. It's complicated because of many things, but, definately in order to use it you should start learning Hibernate/JPA, Java SE, RMI and OOP itself. Then you may look into Spring technology.

Answer (score 0):

For Android Java is about **a programming language** and some **core java library**

J2ME is also a mobile application development framework supported by many phones. The common thing between Android and J2ME is only the Java language. Both have different set of terminology for development.

Web: It's about target platform and programming model. Android's Java is for mobile development platform. Here the apis, software stack, concepts are totally different from what are there for Web development.